# Preferred no of columns for a Fact table?

Tags: data-warehouse, fact-table

I have my Fact table with Policy data in it & I want to add Policy Products details to the warehouse.
One policy gets different types of products and the values also are dynamic.

*Eg: Policy01 may have two products Building & Contents where sum insured values are 1000 & 500 respectively. And Policy02 get Building only of 750.*

There are like 30 products available and I need to store sum insured value, gross & net premiums of each product per policy. 
So if I add separate column for each product type into fact table it'll add live 120 more columns (currently there are 23 columns). Also max 5 products per policy so only 20 columns will contain values & others remain empty.

Is it ok to have 100+ columns for fact table? Is it ok to keep this many empty values in a row?
Or is there any other approach I can solve this?

I'm a novice at DWH and hope someone can shed me some light how to add these to my fact table.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to add a product dimension:
[image]

You can then return totals by policy:

```
SELECT
    PolicyKey
    SUM(PolicyProductValue) AS PolicyValue
FROM
    Fact.PolicyProductValue
GROUP BY
    PolicyKey
;
```

Or product:

```
SELECT
    ProductKey,
    SUM(PolicyProductValue) AS ProductValue
FROM
    Fact.PolicyProductValue
GROUP BY
    ProductKey
;
```

Or both:

```
SELECT
    PolicyKey,
    ProductKey,
    SUM(PolicyProductValue) AS PolicyProductValue
FROM
    Fact.PolicyProductValue
GROUP BY
    PolicyKey,
    ProductKey
;
```

This approach moves the products from the columns to the rows.

This technique offers several benefits:

1. It is easier to add new rows than columns.
2. You can add common filters to `Dim.Product`.
3. `Dim.Product` provides a location to create product hierarchies.  Example:

`| Product Key | Product Name | Product Group       |
    | ----------- | ------------ | --------------------|
    | 0           | Building     | Building & Contents |
    | 1           | Contents     | Building & Contents |`

Answer (score 2):

It's not ok to have 100+ columns in a fact table; it's a symptom of an incorrect data model (the same is true for missing values - a well designed fact table shouldn't have any).

The logic of the fact table design is the following:
First, deside on the table "granularity" - the most atomic level of data it will contain. In your case, data granularity is defined by Policy number + Product. Together they uniquely identify the most detailed information available to you.

Then, identify your "facts". Typically, facts are pieces of data that you can aggregate (sum, count, average, etc). In your case, they are Insured_Value, Gross_Premium, Net_Premium.

Finally, define business context for these facts (dimensions). In your case, they are Policy and Product (most likely, you will also have some kind of Date).

Your resulting fact table should look something like this:

- Policy_Date
- Policy_Number
- Product_ID
- Insured_Value
- Gross_Premium
- Net_Premium

Policy_Date will provide connection to "Calendar" dimension, Product_ID will connect to "Product" dimension (table that contains your 30 products and their descriptions).

Policy_Number is what's called a "Degenerate Dimension" - it's an ID that is usually not connected to any dimensions (but could if you need to). It's stored in a fact table just as a reference. Some people add "Policy" dimension to the model, but usually it's a design mistake - such dimensions are too "tall", comparable in size to the fact table, which can dramatically slow down your model performance. It's usually better to split policy attributes into multiple small dimesions and leave the policy number as a degenerate dimension.

So, your typical policy with 5 products will be represented as 5 records in the fact table, rather than one record with 5 fields. This is the critical difference - never, ever store information (products in your case) in the name of the fact table fields.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation RADO, if I go for products on fact table instead of policy how can I link dimensions? Those are mostly for the policy. Then I'll have to link the same dimension for each product?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "link the same dimension for each product". Can you give me an example? 

The way you described your data model, you'll just need to link dimension "Product" and the fact table on Product_ID. If you have other dimensions, you will need to add their IDs to the fact table.